# Rails Conversion from ActiveSupport::TimeZone to Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Given an ActiveSupport::TimeZone object, I'd like to retrieve a country name or code. Is there anything built into rails that can do this? Any gems? I don't see anything in the Rails documentation that jumps out at me as providing this conversion. I understand that there is some ambiguity here, but am just looking for the country of the city specified in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, you can use `TZInfo::Country.get('AU')`, where `AU` is a country code. 
refer this link [get country from time zone](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo)

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone` is a class concerned with timezones, it is not specific to country. Therefore, you can't get the country name or code.

However, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` can return its name, which may or may not be a country. For example:

```
> Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fdf7d526660 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: nil,nil,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 0,0,UTC>>>>
> Time.zone = 'Hawaii'
> Time.zone.name
=> "Hawaii"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This isn't quite what I was looking for though. What I ended up doing was keeping the selection of time zone and country separate and using the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) for country selection.

Comment: Cool. Hope this answer helped a little :)